# biblatex: usenglish not supported and both isbn and issn using alphabetic style

Tags: biblatex

I'd like to get the most accurate citation of http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-29099-2 using biblatex+biber.  However, whichever entry type I try, I get either only ISBN or only ISSN, whereas I'd like to have both.  The best approximation so far has been achieved with with `book`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[USenglish,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,sortcites=true,maxnames=99,useprefix=true,dateabbrev=true,autolang=other,abbreviate=false]{biblatex}%%% this line stays as it is
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mwe.bib}
@string{spvl   = "Sprin\-ger Ver\-lag"}
@book{Geisberger_Broy_-_agendaCPS,
    series={acatech STUDIE},
    title={agendaCPS},
    subtitle={Integrierte Forschungsagenda \foreignlanguage{USenglish}{cyber-physical systems}},
    author={Eva Geisberger and Manfred Broy},
    date={2012-10-10},
    publisher=spvl,
    isbn={978-3-642-29098-5},
    doi={10.1007/978-3-642-29099-2},
    pagetotal=297,
    note={\mkbibacro{\foreignlanguage{USenglish}{eBook ISBN}}: 978-3-642-29099-2. \mkbibacro{\foreignlanguage{USenglish}{ISSN}}: 2192-6174. \mkbibacro{\foreignlanguage{USenglish}{Series E-ISSN}}: 2193-8962},
    langid={ngerman}}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{Geisberger_Broy_-_agendaCPS}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Feeding this to the loop over `pdflatex mwe && biber --isbn-normalise mwe`, we get

[image: output]

As you see, quite a lot of stuff went into `note` in the source (which I don't like; I'd prefer to have `issn={2192-6174}`, perhaps similar for the online ISBN and online ISSN), “eBook” and ”Series E-ISSN“ were printed in small caps in the PDF (as opposed to the publisher's Web page, so, differences in the capitalization were lost), and ISBN is too far from eBook ISBN (whereas it'd be logical to move them closer together).  Is there any better way? (Is it, perhaps, possible to modify the `book` or `periodical` entry style to include both ISBN and ISSN (ideally also their online versions) or even create a new, custom entry style based on the two entry styles that addresses the deficiencies?)

Any by the way, why do we get “Package biblatex Warning: Language 'usenglish' not supported.” in the log file?

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be three questions here. I'll respond to them in reverse to save code till the end.

1. How is it possible to get `book` entries to show `issn` fields?
2. What's the best way to show metadata for multiple editions in one source?
3. Why does Biblatex throw a warning for `usenglish`?

The third question will have to be answered by someone else, since Biblatex *does* seem to be loading `usenglish` in some cases by automatically jumping back to `american`, but it still throws a warning. (Incidentally, replacing all mentions of `usenglish` with `american` removes those warnings.)

The second question is maybe best answered with another question: *Is it a good idea to include metadata for multiple editions in one source?* You mention at the start of your question that you want to include the most accurate citation for a source, but your bibliography should ideally reflect the sources you're citing. An electronic edition and a print edition of a book are different editions. If you're not consulting both or there's no fundamental difference between them, then the extra data may not be necessary. If you're citing both because there's some fundamental difference between them, you might best be served by making two different bibliographic entries so that you can distinguish which one you're citing in a given moment. And if you're including the data for the sake of completeness, you might still make two entries, and then reference a simplified version of the secondary edition with a `related` field (see below).

The first question necessitates redefining the bibliography driver for the `book` entry type. By default, `alphabetic.bbx` doesn't pay attention to the `issn` field for books, just like it ignores `isbn` for articles. But it's maybe reasonable to reference the series a volume is printed in, so you can copy the bibliographic driver for `alphabetic.bbx` (actually found in `standard.bbx`) and insert an extra line referencing the `issn` field. This redefinition should come in the preamble of the document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[USenglish,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,sortcites=true,maxnames=99,useprefix=true,dateabbrev=true,autolang=other,abbreviate=false]{biblatex}%%% this line stays as it is
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mwe.bib}
@string{spvl   = "Sprin\-ger Ver\-lag"}
@book{Geisberger_Broy_-_agendaCPS_print,
    title={agendaCPS},
    author={Geisberger and Broy},
    isbn={978-3-642-29098-5},
    issn={2192-6174},
    langid={ngerman}}
@book{Geisberger_Broy_-_agendaCPS,
    series={acatech STUDIE},
    title={agendaCPS},
    subtitle={Integrierte Forschungsagenda \foreignlanguage{usenglish}{cyber-physical systems}},
    author={Eva Geisberger and Manfred Broy},
    date={2012-10-10},
    publisher=spvl,
    isbn={978-3-642-29099-2},
    issn={2193-8962},
    doi={10.1007/978-3-642-29099-2},
    pagetotal=297,
    langid={ngerman},
    related={Geisberger_Broy_-_agendaCPS_print},
    relatedtype={reprintof}}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}%
    \newunit
    \printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}
\cite{Geisberger_Broy_-_agendaCPS}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Notice that I've simplified the entry for the print edition, which is referenced in the `related` field of the electronic edition. When typeset, the PDF looks like this:

[image: book entry referencing isbn and issn of two editions]

It may be nice to replace "Reprint of" ("Nachdruck von") with something like "E-print of". Do this by creating a bibstring and changing `reprintof` with your new bibstring.

Comment: The only warning about `usenglish` I get from the MWE in the question is `No localisation for language 'usenglish' loaded. Please rerun LaTeX to ensure languages can be requested properly.` and that warning goes away after the recommended LaTeX run and does not return (until the aux files are deleted). Do you get something else?

Comment: The warning I see persists across LaTeX runs: 
`Package biblatex Warning: Language 'usenglish' not supported.
(biblatex)                Using dummy definitions on input line 22.` 
I've not yet updated to the July release of Biblatex, so the discrepancy might be there.

Comment: It could also have to do with the new definition of `\MakeLowercase` in the LaTeX kernel. `\mkbibacro` may apply `\MakeLowercase`. I can imagine that the order of `\foreignlanguage` and `\mkbibacro` causes issues, because the `USenglish` is incorrectly lowercased. Maybe the issue goes away if things are inverted to `\foreignlanguage{USenglish}{\mkbibacro{eBook ISBN}}` etc.

Comment: @moewe It does!